# Is there any algorithm to improve my code?

Tags: algorithm

SEAWEED

You're given **k** days and **n** seaweed.

(1 ≤ n ≤ 1000, 1 ≤ k ≤ 10^17)

At the very first day, you have **n** seaweed at level 1

The next day, that **n** seaweed will reproduce, every **n** seaweed at level i will reproduce **n*i** seaweed at level 1, these level 1 seaweed will start reproduce after the day end.

Every seaweed at level i will become level i+1.

After **k** days, return the total number of seaweed
(im very sorry, if you dont understand the problem, i'm very bad at translating)

EXAMPLE:

INPUT : 3 3

OUTPUT : 39

EXPLANATION:

DAY 0 : 3 SEAWEED

DAY 1 : 3 Level 1 , 3 Level 2 ...

Total seaweed at day 1 = 6

DAY 2 : 3 + 3 * 2 Level 1 (there are 3 level 1 and 3 level 2, so 3 * 1 + 3 * 2 = 9), 3 Level 2 , 3 Level 3

Total seaweed at day 2 = 15

DAY 3: 9 + 3 * 2 + 3 * 3 = 24 (at day 2 there is 9 level 1, 3 level 2 and 3 level 3) Level 1 , 3 + 3*2 = 9 Level 2 , 3 Level 3 , 3 Level 4

Total seaweed at day 3 = 39

TOTAL OF SEAWEED : 39

Can you help me find any algorithm for this problem? and shorten my problem into one sentence

My code doesn't seem so fast

Here's my code for the problem:

```
def solver(n,k):
    storage = [n]
    for i in range(k):
        reproduction = 0
        for j in range(len(storage)):
            reproduction += storage[j]*(j+1)
        storage = [reproduction] + storage
    return sum(storage)%(10**9+7)
```

Some more test case:

INPUT : n = 4, k = 3

OUTPUT : 52

INPUT : n = 5, k = 5

OUTPUT : 445

Comment: What are the constraints over n and k?

Comment: (1 ≤ n ≤ 1000, 1 ≤ k ≤ 10^17)

Comment: It is worth to show also example for day 3

Comment: Is this from an ongoing contest or do you have some link where I can submit my code and check the testcases.

Comment: i'll edit some more test case for you, it's on my school site so you can't submit your code

Comment: If you have working code that you're wanting to have reviewed for suggestions for improvement, you should ask about it on [codereview.se] instead - that's exactly what it was created to do. This site is for questions about non-working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution might be expressed through [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number):

```
solver(n,k) = n*Fib(2*k+1)
```

and Fibonacci numbers for extremely high k values (using modulo 10**9+7) might be calculated with matrix exponentiation method [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form)

Comment: Can you tell me why it should be (2*k+1) instead of k

Comment: Because we have sequence `Gn=G(n-1) + G(n-1)+2*G(n-2) +3*G(n-3)+...+n*G0`. that  rises "twice as fast" comparing with Fibonacci sequence, so jumps two steps of Fibonacci seq. at every step. It might be proven by math. induction (quite long though) . `+1`  is just choice of origin (if we start Fib. seq from 1, we should remove this one)

Answer (score 0):

The first insight is that the function is linear in `n`. You can imagine each of the `n` initial seaweed plants as a separate lineage; their descendants do not interfere with each other, so if you double `n`, you double the answer. So if you solve `f(1, k)` then you can get `f(n, k)` simply by multiplying by `n`. You could -- by some slow calculation -- make a table of values of `f(1, k)` for many values of `k`, then compute `f(n, k)` for any `(n, k)` that is requested.

The second insight is to work out e.g. `f(1, 5)` on paper and see the patterns in the numbers. If you are a mathematician at heart, you will recognise some terms from the Fibonacci sequence. (If you are *really* a mathematician at heart, you will *prove* the pattern.) Then you can write the formula for `f(n, k)`, and some fast code to calculate it.